# Css/Js: Placing a toolbar on the left side of the screen without overlapping with existing page elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a plugin that helps designers/front-end developers in choosing colors for different elements in their design. I don't want to go into details know. The main idea is, that they insert a javascript file in their html body, and that script will create a kind-of toolbar on the page. I want this toolbar to appear in the left side of the screen, but **not overlap with existing elements on the page**. So (probably) I have to move the whole body to right N pixels (if the toolbar is N pixels wide).

Here is a half-baked demo:
http://jsbin.com/ifizal/2/edit

Basically I set a left margin for the body. It works fine, assuming that there are no elements with `position: absolute` on the page. If there are, the design will be broken. So how can I move the whole body to right, including elements positioned `absolute`?

Any other approach is welcomed, the main problem is this:

**Placing a toolbar on the left side of the screen (N pixels wide), but without overlapping with existing page elements.**

Comment: And if there are elements with `position:fixed` ? And if the body contains scripts changing the elements positions ?

Comment: The best solution might be to use frames or iframes.

Comment: @dystroy: Good point. It seems to be a complex problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the element, append it as first element in body and add margin-left to body.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ifizal/3/edit

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="placeHolder"></div>
  Hello world!
  <br/><br/>
  <button onclick="javascript:addToolbar();">addToolbar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}


body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;  
}

#toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f6f6f6;   
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#placeHolder{
  display: none;  
}
```

Vanilla Javascript

```
function addToolbar(){

  var bodyz = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  var placeHolder = document.getElementById("placeHolder");

  var toolbar = document.createElement('div');
  toolbar.setAttribute('id','toolbar');
  toolbar.innerHTML = 'Toolbar';  
  bodyz.insertBefore(toolbar, placeHolder);

  bodyz.style.marginLeft = "60px";
}
```

Comment: First, thank for the answer Andrea. The problem is that this doesn't seems to solve the problem of existing elements positioned absolute or fixed on the page.

Comment: Not for fixed, but yes for absolute (try it ;).

As pointed out by @dystroy, there're several potential drawbacks in this approach, by the way for the fixed elements you can fetch ALL the elements in the page, check each one to see if position is fixed then, if it is, add 60px to their left property.

Comment: Yes, it solved to problem for `absolutes` if we add `position: relative` to body: http://jsbin.com/ifizal/10/edit. Thank you for this solution, I will go with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the page content into a DIV with position relative in css. Then just move that DIV.
The elements with position absolute inside that DIV are relativelly to its position /margins.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my comment on the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of specific problems with this idea but I think the biggest problem will be that the toolbar will always be contained within the body - so any special positioning of the body will also move the toolbar.

For example...

```
body {
    position: relative;
    left: 60px;
}
```

Will move the toolbar and the rest of the page.

You might want to consider putting a div around the rest of the content and relatively positioning that instead.  I assume you are hitting this problem because you cannot just change the pages HTML to incorporate the toolbar?

You could use javascript to do all of this - grab the HTML content of the body, add the toolbar and div, then add the original body content into the div.

Comment: Wrapping the body content in a div and then move it is my plan B, and can be a good alternative solution, however it has it's own side effects. Thank you guys for the idea. Will keep you updated about this.